# How to specify an ActiveMQ Topic username/password using org.apache.activemq.web.AjaxServlet

Tags: ajax, jms, activemq-classic

All,

I am using the ActiveMQ 5.5 AjaxServlet to enable ActiveMQ queue/topic listening via JavaScript.

This approach works fine when the topic is not secured by username & password; however, once it is, I am struggling to figure out the proper configuration to authenticate the topic subscription.

Most of the ActiveMQ documentation is based around Spring, however I am simply using the AjaxServlet in this situation.  Therefore, I am left with the web.xml as the means for specifying authentication parameters.  Perhaps I am just using the incorrect param name?  None of the ActiveMQ Web Demos connect to a secured topic.

Open to suggestions!

Here is my current web.xml file that I deploy along with my "ActiveMQ-JS" WAR.  I have also tried specifying the `?userName=xyz&password=xyz` within the `brokerURL` itself, but this seemed to cause problems.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>activemq-js</display-name>
 <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.activemq.brokerURL</param-name>
    <param-value>failover://tcp://127.0.0.1:61616</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.activemq.userName</param-name>
    <param-value>username_to_topic</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.activemq.password</param-name>
    <param-value>password_to_topic</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.activemq.embeddedBroker</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>AjaxServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.apache.activemq.web.AjaxServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>AjaxServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/amq/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
  <filter-name>session</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.ContinuationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>session</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom ajax servlet which will extend AjaxServlet and change username and password.

```
  public class MyAjaxServlet extends AjaxServlet{

       protected AjaxWebClient getAjaxWebClient( HttpServletRequest request ) {
           AjaxWebClient client = super.getAjaxWebClient(request);
           client.setUsername("test");
           client.setPassword("test");
           return client;
       }

}
```

Update web.xml with your custom ajax servlet.

```
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>MyAjaxServlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>com.example.esb.web.MyAjaxServlet</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>maximumReadTimeout</param-name>
        <param-value>120000</param-value>
     </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     <async-supported>true</async-supported>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>MyAjaxServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/amq/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```